# Hypernym for lossy or lossless?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, hypernyms

Generally, there exist two types of [compression algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossless_compression) which have the feature to be lossless or lossy. What is the noun to reference this feature?

The word **lossiness** seems to be plausible to me. Is it correct?

Comment: *accuracy, precision, exactness?*

Comment: The awkward thing is that the lossiness of compression algorithms can actually contribute to better overall fidelity (relative to total data size), if the initial sample rate is higher.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think there's a term for the binary condition "100% accurate" vs. "not 100% accurate) you ask about. But there are plenty of terms for the *spectra* of accuracy. The best adjective I would use is [**fidelity**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/fidelity).

> 5. accuracy; exactness:
>    The speech was transcribed with great fidelity.
> 6. *Audio, Video.* the degree of accuracy with which sound or images are recorded or reproduced.

<sub>Source: dictionary.com</sub>

In use:

> What is the fidelity of the compression algorithm?
>
> It's configurable between 80% lossy and completely lossless.

Answer (score 6):

'lossiness' is valid in some circles. I heard it quite a bit in conversation when working with image compression in grad school. But it is definitely a neologism and not completely accepted. Even a web search doesn't turn up a lot, but here's a IEEE paper that uses it, so that is some amount of legitimacy.
[Link](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1208667)

PatrickM's answer of 'fidelity' is what I would use in print.

Comment: “Lossy” is also a neologism.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need *lossiness*, ***loss*** itself is a noun.

> This compression algorithm introudces ***loss***.
>   That compression alogrithm does not introduce any ***loss***.

Another word to consider is ***degradation***.

> : the act or process of damaging or ruining something
>   <sub>[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/degradation)</sub>

Comment: *Loss* is what is lost. *Lossiness* is the degree to which some information is lost. It applies to an algorithm (e..g, a compression or conversion algorithm).

Comment: @Drew: I was addressing the question of a noun to address the feature of the algorithm, not the degree.

Comment: The problem with *loss* is that it is an everyday word with a wide range of applications, so (depending on the context) it may not always be obvious what kind of loss is intended by it. *Lossless* and *lossy*, on the other hand, are technical terms with fairly precise meanings.

Comment: @jsw29 I am not sure I understand the point. The context in this case was "compression algorithms". There are many common words that are adopted into technical jargon.